# How do you load a wave file as 32-bit integers?

Tags: python, scipy, wav

How do you load a wave file as 32-bit integers?

I was using `scipy.io.wavfile.read` to load a wave file, but it returns a `ndarray` with a `dtype` of int16, which is a problem since the wave file I wanted to load had values larger than what a 16-bit integer could hold.

Apparently, wave files should be able to store 32-bit integers, so is there a way to do it? Or does the fact that `scipy.io.wavfile.read` returned an array of 16-bit integers mean that my wave file was 16-bit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Or does the fact that scipy.io.wavfile.read returned an array of 16-bit integers mean that my wave file was 16-bit?"* Yes.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser My bad, I don't know why I typed 64-bit integer there (I meant 16). Welp. I figured that it might have been the wav file not the scipy function.